# Wrap each line in a text file in apostrophes and add comma to end of lines

Tags: sed

My actual text document contains the  following lines.

```
san.20140226.sbc.UTM    
san.201402261.UTM    
san.2014022613.UTM
```

I want the below output:

```
'san.20140226.sbc.UTM',
'san.201402261.UTM',
'san.2014022613.UTM',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this sed command,

```
sed "s/.*/'&',/g" file
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'san.20140226.sbc.UTM' | sed "s/.*/'&',/g"
'san.20140226.sbc.UTM',
```

**OR**

```
$ echo 'san.20140226.sbc.UTM' | sed "s/^/'/;s/$/',/"
'san.20140226.sbc.UTM',
```

`^` matches the start of a line and `$` matches the end of a line.